# Play Framework: How can I change the default password for in-memory sa user?

Tags: playframework

I'm trying to set a custom password for the sa user. My application.conf contains

```
db=mem
db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL
db.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.user=sa
db.pass=newpass
```

...and the play framework appears to be overriding it inside play.db.DBPlugin

```
if(p.getProperty("db.url") != null && p.getProperty("db.url").startsWith("jdbc:h2:mem:")) {
    p.put("db.driver", "org.h2.Driver");
    p.put("db.user", "sa");
    p.put("db.pass", "");
}
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware this is because H2 in memory mode uses a default user/password, as it's a RAM based db and it will be removed when the application stops and any changes to the user will be lost.

To avoid this you have to either use a "file" (not "mem") instance of H2 or some other database.

I can't think of an scenario where you want a memory database and changing the password is relevant. Could you explain the scenario and why you want to change the password? Maybe we can help by pointing an alternative.

Comment: Well, I wanted to use the in-memory database because I have lots of RAM available on the server, and benchmarks I've seen show in-memory H2 is way faster than the alternatives I have available. Also, the database in my app doesn't need to be writable/updatable after the initial data load (or patches down the road). So, I have a job that runs on application start, that populates my database. After that, all requests are database reads, not writes. I don't like having a database account active with a blank/default password, for security reasons.

Comment: @DaveS ok that's a quite specific scenario to be honest. Only alternative seems to edit the framework. Although to be honest, being a read only db that's in memory, having the default user/pwd shouldn't be a huge deal security wise. All the data is available too as a file in the system (the one that the job loads) so I would be so worried about that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was afraid it would involve editing the Play source code. I'll probably stick with the default then. It works very well.